# Hide the group header of an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I want to hide the group header of a group at `grouppPosition` in an ExpandableListView. How can I do this in the getGroupView method of the Custom ExpandableListAdapter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a reference to your **ExpandableListView** inside your **CustomExpandableListAdapter** and than:

```
expandableListView.expandGroup(group_position); // to expand
expandableListView.collapseGroup(group_position); // to collapse
```

Comment: This is not what I meant. I made the group always expanded. Now I want to hide the header which collapses the list. In other words, I want to make it like a simple ListView without a header.

Comment: Ok if I correctly understood your question, you should make the header with visibility gone and not clickable.

Comment: @AndroidGorilllla Setting visibility to Gone it still takes space on the UI. So cannot use visibility.Gone